# Capture app exit on Phonegap app?

Tags: cordova

I'm in the process of converting my web-app to a phonegap one, and am wondering if there is a way to listen for when the user exits the app so I can flag them in my database as being 'offline'?

Is this possible?

My other thought is, if they are flagged as 'online' in your database, how do you change it to 'offline' if they turn off their phone ie are apps able to react to the phone being turned off before the phone powers down?

Currently I'm using polling every 30 secs to update an expiry time for the user, and if the sever doesn't get updated, then they are flagged as being offline. But I want to move away from polling altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No all device vendors allow an app to exit explictitly e.g. Apple. as this might be detected as a crash also
You can take a look at the Pause and resume events in PhoneGap

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/cordova_events_events.md.html#pause
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/cordova_events_events.md.html#resume

Comment: Thanks Rajarshi. I will chnage my code so that the offline status doesn't kick in for 15 minutes, to give them time to return to the app if they leave.